# Finding sum of a series involving complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, complex-numbers

$\cos\theta$ + $i\sin\theta$ is a root of the equation $x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+....a_n=0$ and we have to find the value of $\sum_{r=1}^{n}a_r\cos{r\theta}$  (all $a_r$ coefficients are real)

I tried putting the complex number into the given equation and used De Moivre's theorem for integral indices but it doesn't generate the required sum. I can't think of anything after that.

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: Hint: $\;$if $\,w \ne 0\,$ is a root of $\,x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\dots+ a_n\,$ then $\,\dfrac{1}{w}\,$ is a root of $\,1 + a_1 x + \dots + a_nx^n\,$.

Comment: Are you given that $a_r$ is real?

Comment: Yes $a_r$ are real

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using @dxiv's comment,
\begin{gather*}
x^{n} +a_{1} x^{n-1} +a_{2} x^{n-2} +..\ +a_{n} =0\ for\ x=\cos \theta +i\sin \theta \\
Dividing\ the\ equation\ by\ x^{n}\\
a_{n} x^{-n} +a_{n-1} x^{-( n-1)} +...\ +a_{1} x^{-1} +1=0\\
Now\ x^{-k} =(\cos \theta +i\sin \theta )^{-k}\\
=\cos( -k\theta ) +i\sin( -k\theta )\\
=\cos k\theta -i\sin k\theta \\
Thus\ expanding\ the\ terms,\ and\ considering\ only\ the\ real\ part,\\
a_{n}\cos n\theta +a_{n-1}\cos( n-1) \theta +..+a_{1}\cos \theta +1=0\\
\sum _{r=1}^{n} a_{r}\cos r\theta =-1\\
\end{gather*}
Hope this helps!

Comment: How do you know $a_r$ is real????

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh, I meant the real part of the given expression.